# generic method return List<T> from database

Tags: c#, sql, linq, object

Assume I have a model:

```
public class Person
{
public int ID {get;set;}
public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

And have a table in database:

```
person(integer ID, char Name)
```

How can I return IEnumerable (or List) from database when in compiler time model (Person) is unknown. For instance, I think, select method must has the following structure:

```
public List<object> Select(string query, Dictionary<string, object> parameters)
        {
            List<object> listValue = new List<object>();
            using (var command = new MySqlCommand(query, connection))
            {
                #region fill command.Parameters.AddWithValue
                if (parameters != null)
                {
                    foreach (var param in parameters)
                    {
                        if (param.Value == null)
                        {
                            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@" + param.Key, DBNull.Value);
                            continue;
                        }
                        DateTime _date = new DateTime();
                        if (DateTime.TryParse(param.Value.ToString(), out _date))
                        {
                            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@" + param.Key, _date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));
                            continue;
                        }
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@" + param.Key, param.Value);
                    }
                }
                #endregion

                if (connection.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Closed) connection.Open();
                try
                {
                    using (MySqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader(System.Data.CommandBehavior.CloseConnection))
                    {
                        while (reader.Read())
                        {
                            object newObject = new object();

                           // What must I do there?

                            listValue.Add(new { });
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex) { }
                finally
                {
                    if (connection.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
                        connection.Close();
                }
            }
            return listValue;
}
```

Comment: `catch (Exception ex) { }` - Side note, this is a bad idea.  Why wouldn't you want to know why something might have failed?  Exceptions tend to contain very useful information for correcting problems.

Comment: Where is that model, when is it not part of compilation? If it is not part of compilation, then you dont have model. You only have SQL database and want to read it. It is easy solution from down there.

Comment: Maybe, I wish using a generic Select model for my models (Person, Customer ...)

Comment: That's more clear. You want a generic data access method for all possible model-table mappings. In this case, you'll find many answers on SO already

Comment: David, I use this method in MVC, and there I will have a error controller

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/385178/generic-data-access-functions among many others...

Comment: ErOx, in what direction I must dig? :)

Comment: That link provides a concrete solution to the problem you are trying to solve. There are many others like it on SO

Comment: You have tagged the question with LINQ, but there is nothing in here that looks like any kind of LINQ. Hmm, speaking of LINQ, why don't you just scrap the above code and go for LINQ2SQL or Entity Framework?

Comment: Albin Sunnanbo, I want working with MySQL directly (usinq query)

Comment: Sounds like this needs an ORM layer; NHibernate or Entity Framework or something...

Comment: You should take a look at [Massive](https://github.com/robconery/massive)

Answer (score 0):

I think u need a new argument like 'Func" to let invoker decide how to convert a datarow from database to the entity